# iOS 6 UIWebView Video Not Rotating

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which displays a website with some embedded videos.  I've noticed that when I try to rotate the phone while a video is playing, it will not rotate on iOS 6.  Previous version work fine.  I even tried a tumblr feed and it seems to be broken there as well.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: are you implementing the `suppportedInterfaceOrientations` method?

Comment: Yes I am implementing that method.  I am still not seeing the view rotate though.